# jQuery Remove item from basket debug

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

I have a problem with my jQuery remove item from basket.

If I wait 10s or so after adding an item to the basket, it removes without issue.
If I add an item to the basket, realise I made a mistake then hit the remove button (within a few seconds), the page reloads - not what was intended.

I am guessing that this could be because the jQuery event has not been attached to the remove item from basket id as yet...

Is there any way of speeding this process up or is there something I have done wrong in my jQuery as it's quite noticeable...

http://goldealers.co.uk/calc-test

Many thanks in advance.

I am binding to the event as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('.remove').click(function(data) {
    var pid = jQuery(this).attr('name');
      jQuery.post('https://goldealers.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/gd/tables.php', 
        { pid: pid, remove: 'true' }, 
            function(data) {
                jQuery("#quoteTable").load("https://goldealers.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/gd/tables.php?table=quoteTable");
                jQuery("#quoteTotal").load("https://goldealers.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/gd/tables.php?table=quoteTotalTable");          
            },
        "json");        
    return false;
});
```

});

The Html which it binds to is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="remove" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="6" />
<input type="image" src="https://goldealers.co.uk/media/delete.png" name="6" class="remove"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post some relevant code

Comment: How are you binding the event to the newly added element

Comment: If you don't add the relevant code here, this question will not be useful for anyone else. Thus, questions with only an off-site link often get closed as too localised.

Comment: apologies... code of how I am binding to the event added to the question

Comment: The code you have added doesn't seem to be causing the issue. "some code" != two lines. "Some code" = anything that could be relevant to solving the issue.

Comment: This will only attach the click handler to the elements that are present at the moment the handler is attached. I can't see how that relates to timing, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Well this is the only piece of code which binds to the event after it has been added.

Comment: @Gravy _when_ is this piece of code called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the event listener live. You can do this by changing it to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    ...
})
```